# C# Dictionary to Dictionary AutoMapping

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dictionary, mapping

I need to patch values of one dictionary with another adding new keys on the fly. I need to save new keys and replace existing ones in order to complete patch function. There has to be existing mapping I cannot access. Or what mapping profile should I write?

```
[Test]
public void DictionaryMapping()
{
    // Arrange
    var write = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "Key1", 100 },
        { "Key2", true }
    };
            var patch = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "Key2", false },
        { "Key3", "Additional"}
    };

    // Act
    Mapper.Map(patch, write);

    // Assert
    Assert.That(write["Key1"], Is.EqualTo(100));
    Assert.That(write["Key2"], Is.EqualTo(false));
    Assert.That(write["Key3"], Is.EqualTo("Additional"));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can merge dictionaries like this:

```
foreach(var keyValue in patch)
    write[keyValue.Key] = keyValue.Value;
```

It will overwrite existing and create new ones for non-existing.

Comment: This is not in the context of Automapper.

Comment: @Roel I also have the feeling that the word 'automapper' and merging dictionaries have a lot in common.

Comment: Sorry I red the title wrong. I found this question when searching for a solution using automapper but this is totally not related.